# The way to handle global variables in a class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

have a php code like this,(part of the php function here)going to convert it in to C#.

```
function jaktDate2()
{
    Global $nameofselectbox,$startYear,$endYear,$year,
    $startDate,$endDate,$startMounth,$endMounth,$startDay,$endDay;
    $today = getdate();
    $year=$today['year'];
    $mounth=$today['mon'];
    $day=$today['mday'];
```

my C# code try is this,

```
  public class HuntingDate
    {
        public string StartYear;
        public string EndYear;
        public string Year;
        public DateTime StartDate;
        public DateTime EndDate;
        public string StartMonth;
        public string EndMonth;
        public DateTime StartDay;
        public DateTime EndDay;


    }
```

I'm starting this way.. is this way correct? What should i do next ?

Comment: I'm a bit unsure about the inner workings of `global` in *php*, but `public static` is the correct substitution in *C#* I believe. And has been pointed out as an answer, if possible use properties instead of fields. Ex `public static string StartMonth {get; set;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you're defining seems more like a random grab-bag of values and less like a well-defined class.  What do all of these values actually represent?

```
public string StartYear;
public string EndYear;
public string Year;
public DateTime StartDate;
public DateTime EndDate;
public string StartMonth;
public string EndMonth;
public DateTime StartDay;
public DateTime EndDay;
```

For example, what is the difference between `StartDate` and `StartDay`?  What are `StartYear` and `StartMonth`?  What is this class actually *defining*?  It looks like you're trying to break up the `DateTime` values into components.  You don't need to do that.  A simple `DateTime` value will sufficiently store the necessary information, and you can get the components directly from that value:

```
public DateTime StartDate;
public DateTime EndDate;
```

If you need to know the month, for example, you can get it from that value:

```
myObject.StartDate.Month;
```

To continue to improve the class, you'll want to use properties instead of public members.  In C#, those would look like this:

```
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

These are specifically called auto-implemented properties.  They're compiler short-hand for full properties:

```
private DateTime _startDate;
public DateTime StartDate
{
    get { return _startDate; }
    set { _startDate = value; }
}
// repeat for EndDate
```

The benefit of properties is that the class is exposing a little less about its internal structure.  And if you need to add any logic to the class (such as checking specific bounds of the date, like making sure no StartDate is in the past) then you can add it to the properties without breaking the binary compatibility of the class.  So consuming code never needs to know the difference.  For example:

```
private DateTime _startDate;
public DateTime StartDate
{
    get { return _startDate; }
    set
    {
        if (value < DateTime.Now)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Start Date must not be in the past: {0}", value.ToString()));
        _startDate = value;
    }
}
```

You can continue to take this even further by continuing to define the behavior of this class.  Even having these properties exposed still makes the class more of a "data structure" than an "object."  (For further reading on data/object anti-symmetry, I recommend Clean Code by Robert Martin.)  The goal for a proper object-oriented design would be for the object to hide its data and expose methods that internally perform stateful actions on that data.

For example, if you needed to extend `EndDate` by a day, you could do this:

```
myObject.EndDate += new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
```

But a more object-oriented approach (sticking with the "tell, don't ask" principal) would be to tell the object itself to extend the time, not directly tell its data to extend the time (thereby "asking" the object for its data in the process, which arguably also violates the Law Of Demeter):

```
myObject.ExtendEndDate(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
```

or even:

```
myObject.ExtendEndDateInDays(1);
```

You would just need to implement such a method on the object, and that method would *internally* extend the value of `EndDate`.

The class itself should encapsulate all of the functionality necessary for the concept it represents.  It can provide public read access to its internal members if absolutely necessary, but from a design perspective it's worth asking yourself what kind of queries really need to be made against the object's data and to provide more targeted methods for those queries, rather than direct access to the class' data members.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
public int Num { get; set; }
```

Instead of this:

```
private int _num;
public int Num { get { return _num; } set { _num = value; } }
```

And as to the last part:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
int year = today.Year;
int month = today.Month;
int day = today.Day;
```

Note that `today` will also have the hour, minute, second, and milliseconds even. If you only want to `Date` part of `Now`, or of any other DateTime object (aka "trim" the "little counts" starting from hours and downwards) - you can do:

```
DateTime dateOnly = someDate.Date;

// someDate: 2.4.2012 10:04:12:0004
// dateOnly: 2.4.2012 00:00:00:0000
```

And it also looks like you're going to need to create a DateTime object from Year, Month and Day, so:

```
this.StartDate = new DateTime(startYear, startMonth, startDay);
```

**Edit**

```
// This gets called the moment you initialize the object
public HuntingDate()
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    int year = today.Year;
    int month = today.Month;
    int day = today.Day;

    // more logic, to set StartDate and EndDate
}
```

Now from the outside you could do someplace:

```
HuntingDate hd = new HuntingDate();
DateTime sd = hd.StartDate;
DateTime ed = hd.EndDate;
```

Comment: @Yorye Nathan i got this error.. "A field initializer cannot reference the non static field,method or property"

Comment: You probably tried to put the code in the class as it is. You should use it in a method or in the constructor of the class, depending on your need. See me soon-edit.

Comment: @Yorye Nathan int year = today.Year; in here today red underlined & show.Further clarification See this link[link](http://postimage.org/image/s7flvhscr/)

Comment: Normal code should be in an executable scope. The scope you wrote the code in is generally the class - which just holds fields and members and methods, etc. You should write the code inside a method or a constructor (a "method" that gets called when you initialize the object) - see my edit to see how you would actually do it and use it from the outside. In general, I suggest learning C# by the book, step by step, because it seems you have a lot to learn. Good luck! :)

Comment: @Yorye Nathan solved.thanks.yes i'm a beginner.lot to learn.learning step by step

Comment: Onething why you tell me simply set this public int Num { get; set; } instead of my implementation ?

Comment: When you do it that way (called auto-properties), the compiler generates a private backfield (_num) and get/set methods (return _num, _num = value) - all automatically in the background, so the two are practically all the same, except one is a lot nicer to read: I have a public property "Num", and it is accessible get-wise and set-wise. The "Num" property is just an example, of course. This is relevant to any property that is in the most basic form, without any extra logic to the getter/setter.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET you don't need the have a private member variable as the complier will add this during compile time.

Thus you can change

```
private string _year;
public string Year
{
    get { return _year;}
    set { _year = value;}
}
```

into something nicer to read.

```
public string Year { get; set; }
```

To work with dates in .NET you can simply use `System.DateTime.Now` then access any property like `System.DateTime.Now.Day` or `System.DateTime.Now.Year` etc.

Comment: i got this error.. "A field initializer cannot reference the non static field,method or property"

Answer (score 1):

Is better if you define these as properties. [See here for the reason](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx). Anyway the class you wrote is perfectly valid, is just not considered a good practice. You would probably add a constructor too, too initialize some values as the php code does.

Comment: can you provide me a clue ? i'm beginner to C# ?

Comment: public string StartYear { get; set; }; Just google c# properties.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is with properties:

```
public class HuntingDate
{
    public string StartYear{
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string EndYear{
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to do global in c# like you did in PHP.
you can use singleton or static class to do that.

```
public static class HuntingDate
{
    public static string StartYear { get; set; }
}
```

then in your code simply

```
HuntingDate.StartYear = DateTime.Now
```

or

```
var startYear = HuntingDate.StartYear
```

Comment: This is AFAIK the only direct answer to the question. But there could be some discussion regarding the validity of the question...

Answer (score 0):

There is no global variable declaration in C#. Because it is a [Object Oriented Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx) language. In your case you can declare a [static class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
public static class HuntingDate
{
    public static string StartYear 
    {
      get; 
      set; 
    }
    public static string EndYear 
    {
      get; 
      set; 
    }
    // and so on
}
```

And You can access these properties from the class name.

```
HuntingDate.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
HuntingDate.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
```

Comment: @ChathuraRanasinghe just for an example, not for any proper reason..... Anyway this method is used to add days in the datetime object..