# This Member is defined more than once but why?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a php code like this,and I need to convert it to .NET

```
function jaktDate2()
{
Global $nameofselectbox,$startYear,$endYear,$year,
$startDate,$endDate,$startMounth,$endMounth,$startDay,$endDay;
$today = getdate();
$year=$today['year'];
$mounth=$today['mon'];
$day=$today['mday'];
//$year="2004";
//$mounth="7";
//$day="1";

if(round($mounth)<="6"){$startYear=$year-1;$startMounth="-07";$startDay="-01";
$endYear=$year;$endMounth="-06";$endDay="-30";}
elseif(round($mounth)>="7"){$startYear=$year;$startMounth="-07";$startDay="-01";
$endYear=$year+1;$endMounth="-06";$endDay="-30";}

$startDate=$startYear.$startMounth.$startDay;
$endDate=$endYear.$endMounth.$endDay;

return $startDate.";".$endDate;
}
```

Here is my conversion :

```
  public class HuntingDate
    {
        public string StartYear;
        public string EndYear;
        public string Year;
        public DateTime StartDate;
        public DateTime EndDate;
        public string StartMonth;
        public string EndMonth;
        public DateTime StartDay;
        public DateTime EndDay;

        private string _startYear;
        public string StartYear
        {
            get { return _startYear;}
            set { _startYear = value;}
        }

        private string _endYear;
        public string EndYear
       {
        get{return _endYear;}
        set { _endYear = value; }
       }


        private DateTime _startDate;
        public DateTime StartDate
        {
            get { return _startDate;}
            set { _startDate = value;}
        }

        private DateTime _endDate;
        public DateTime EndDate
        {
            get { return _endDate;}
            set { _startDate = value;}
        }

        private string _year;
        public string Year
        {
            get { return _year;}
            set { _year = value;}
        }


        private string _startMonth;
        public string StartMonth
        {
            get { return _startMonth;}
            set { _startMonth = value;}
        }

        private string _endMonth;
        public string EndMonth
        {
        get { return _endMonth;}
        set { _endMonth = value;}
        }

        private DateTime _startDay;
        public DateTime StartDay
        {
            get { return _startDay;}
            set { _startDay = value;}
        }

        private DateTime _endDay;
        public DateTime EndDay
        {
            get { return _endDay; }
            set { _endDay = value; }
        }

        public HuntingDate(){
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        int year = today.Year;
        int month = today.Month;
        DateTime day = today;

        DateTime StartDate = (StartYear+StartMonth+StartDay);
        DateTime EndDate   = (EndYear+EndMonth+EndDay);

        if (month <= 6)
        {
            //string StartYear = Convert.ToString(year-1);
            string StartYear = (year - 1).ToString();
            string StartMonth = Convert.ToString(7);
            string EndYear = Convert.ToString(year);
            string EndMonth = Convert.ToString(6);
            string EndDay = Convert.ToString(30);
        }
        else if(month >= 7)

        {
            string StartYear =Convert.ToString(year);
            string StartMonth = Convert.ToString(7);
            string StartDay = Convert.ToString(1);
            string EndYear = Convert.ToString(year+1);
            string EndMonth = Convert.ToString(6);
            string EndDay = Convert.ToString(30);

        }
        }
        }

        }
```

Problem i found here:

```
        DateTime StartDate = (StartYear+StartMonth+StartDay);
        DateTime EndDate   = (EndYear+EndMonth+EndDay);
```

Problem is :This Member is defined more than once

In here red underlined startyear startmonth startday & and also other part.

Comment: I'm very confused as to why, if you have `public DateTime EndDay;` you need **any** duplicates like `StartYear`, `StartMonth`, etc - seems very redundant.

Comment: Is this some kind of homework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011619/the-way-to-handle-global-variables-in-a-class and why do you ask the same question repeatedly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027059/the-way-to-handle-global-variables-in-a-class-with-assign

Comment: @L.B not a homework.this is our assignment.(university)..But i dont know whois posting.when i implement i got trouble i posted here

Comment: @L.B in this uni work also i tried it out and post the code when i trouble.. otherwise i'm not a person like i just post php code and ask you guys to convert it to .net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you have defined a public field `StartDate` and a property `StartDate`, you can't do that

```
public DateTime StartDate;

public DateTime StartDate
        {
            get { return _startDate;}
            set { _startDate = value;}
        }
```

If you are only going to use `StartDate` as a property then you can get rid of the public field i.e. `public DateTime StartDate;`.

It seems you are defining properties against each public field. That is a syntax error. You may get rid of all the public fields and since you are not doing anything in the properties you may define them like:

```
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: You mean i need to redefine those properties to  public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }  Instead of my property set?

Comment: @expert9, which property set ? you have defined public fields earlier and then you are defining properties. `public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}` is [Auto Implemented property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) which started with C# 3.0

Comment: I'm still unclear about that.I just defining the properties & after that Actually i wanted to assign 3 values to this function like this DateTime StartDate = (StartYear+StartMonth+StartDay); BUT this is not again define know ?

Comment: Because you can't construct a date like that, with three strings concatenated. You need to get a book of C# and start reading the fundamentals.

Comment: Habib.OSU i can't go further with this problem.can you tell me whichone need to rewrite ?

Comment: @expert9, there is an overload of [DateTime constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326682(v=vs.71).aspx) which takes int year, int month, int day. Since your properties are of string type you need to convert them to int and then pass it on

Answer (score 5):

Well look at `StartYear` as an example:

```
// Field declaration
public string StartYear;

// Property declaration with the same name
public string StartYear
{
    get { return _startYear;}
    set { _startYear = value;}
}
```

Why have you got the public fields at all, given that you've *also* got private fields backed by public properties? Just get rid of those public fields.

On a broader note, I wouldn't try to do a verbatim port of code from another platform - I'd try to work out the *intention* and then implement that in an idiomatic way within your .NET code.

Answer (score 1):

You have already declared `StartDate` earlier on. You are trying to re-declare it in the portion that is showing an error.

Comment: @expert9 I think Habib's answer is pointing you in the right direction.